# The element mesh has insufficient quality

Tags: warning-messages, finite-element-method, mesh

I am quite new at FEM. I was trying to create a triangular mesh of a rectangular region. I wanted to do something very basic: Discretize the domain using squares and then subdivide each square into two rectangles. Here is the code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"] 
Nx = 4;
Ny = Nx;
Dx = Subdivide[-2, 2, Nx]
Dy = Subdivide[-2, 2, Ny]
vertcoords = Tuples[{Dx, Reverse@Dy}]
LTidx = {(#1 - 1)*(Nx + 1) + #2, (#1)*(Nx + 1) + #2, (#1)*(Nx + 
         1) + #2 + 1} & @@@ Tuples[{Range[1, Nx], Range[1, Ny]}];
UTidx = {(#1 - 1)*(Nx + 1) + #2 + 
      1, (#1 - 1)*(Nx + 1) + #2, (#1)*(Nx + 1) + #2 + 1} & @@@ 
   Tuples[{Range[1, Nx], Range[1, Ny]}];
Tidx = Flatten[Transpose@{LTidx, UTidx}, 1]
\[CapitalOmega] = 
 ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> vertcoords, 
  "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[Tidx]}]
\[CapitalOmega]["Wireframe"]
```

The plot looks fine to me, but then I get a warning:

```
ToElementMesh::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of -0.866025. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements.
```

I am not entirely sure what's wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the message suggests, the ordering of your incidents is wrong (but in your case consistent). So the fix is simple:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
 ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> vertcoords, 
  "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[Reverse /@ Tidx]}]
\[CapitalOmega]["Wireframe"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, It took me a minute to see what was wrong. When I was writing the 'loop' for the vertex indexes, I was assuming the coordinates to be ordered 'row-wise' from the top left to the bottom right. So, another fix could be
to apply ToElementMesh with the arguments "Coordinates" -> Reverse[Reverse /@ vertcoords], "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[Tidx]}. The double reverse seems nasty, would you have a fix for that?.